# Accessing "current class" from WPF custom MarkupExtension

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, markup-extensions

I'm attempting to write a custom `MarkupExtension` to make my life easier by giving me a better way to specify bindings in XAML. However I would like to know if there is any way I can access the object that represents the file the `MarkupExtension` is used in.

In other words, suppose I have a `UserControl` that defines a particular rendition of a data model of my program. This control has lots of visual stuff like grids, borders and general layout. If I use my `MarkupExtension` on a particular property of some element in this `UserControl`, I want to access the instance of the `UserControl`, without knowing what type it is (I plan on using reflection).

Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In .NET 4.0, they added the [IRootObjectProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xaml.irootobjectprovider.aspx) ability, but unfortunately, it isn't possible in previous versions.  If you are in .NET 4.0, you can do the following:

```
public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    var rootObjectProvider = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IRootObjectProvider)) as IRootObjectProvider;
    var root = rootObjectProvider.RootObject;
    // do whatever you need to do here
}
```

Comment: I *am* using .NET 4! Lemme try it out. :)

Comment: No other way for us, stuck in 3.5?! :((((((((((

Comment: In .NET 3.5, you only have access to IXamlTypeResolver and IProvideValueTarget.  Unfortunately, they won't get you the object at the root of the xaml file you are working in.  IProvideValueTarget will allow you to get the object the extension is called on. I suppose you could walk up its visual tree to get to the root object, if you assume that the root is a UserControl or Window.  This obviously isn't as robust as the .NET 4 solution, but it might work in your scenario.

Comment: Note that for custom controls (not user controls) the root object is the ResourceDictionary :-(